# Equally distribute array in pairs, combination/permutation question

Tags: ruby, combinations, permutation

I'm trying to solve a combination/permutation problem, where I have 10 people, who should review other people's ideas. Each person should review exactly 3 ideas, so for instance:
Person 1: Reviews 2, 3, 4
Person 2: Reviews 5,8, 9
Person 3: Reviews 9, 10, 1
...
etc.

The restrictions are that:

1. 10 is a dynamic number, so the solution should also be dynamic, let's call this variable `m`
2. 3 is also a dynamic number, so the solution should also work for other numbers, let's call this variable `n`.
3. The selection of subarrays (who reviews who) should be random, if the same 10 people take 2 different tests, they shouldn't be evaluating the same people over and over again.

So in short: Out of a group of `m` people, each person should review exactly `n` people, and at the same time receive `n` reviews.

I've been able to find some very useful methods in ruby, such as `combination`, which basically let's me do something like this:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].combination(2).to_a
=> [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6], [1, 7], [1, 8], [1, 9], [1, 10], [2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 5], [2, 6], [2, 7], [2, 8], [2, 9], [2, 10], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6], [3, 7], [3, 8], [3, 9], [3, 10], [4, 5], [4, 6], [4, 7], [4, 8], [4, 9], [4, 10], [5, 6], [5, 7], [5, 8], [5, 9], [5, 10], [6, 7], [6, 8], [6, 9], [6, 10], [7, 8], [7, 9], [7, 10], [8, 9], [8, 10], [9, 10]]
```

And I can also group it in combinations of 3 `(n)`:

```
irb(main):008:0> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].combination(3).to_a
=> [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 5], [1, 2, 6], [1, 2, 7], [1, 2, 8], [1, 2, 9], [1, 2, 10], [1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 6], [1, 3, 7], [1, 3, 8], [1, 3, 9], [1, 3, 10], [1, 4, 5], [1, 4, 6], [1, 4, 7], [1, 4, 8], [1, 4, 9], [1, 4, 10], [1, 5, 6], [1, 5, 7], [1, 5, 8], [1, 5, 9], [1, 5, 10], [1, 6, 7], [1, 6, 8], [1, 6, 9], [1, 6, 10], [1, 7, 8], [1, 7, 9], [1, 7, 10], [1, 8, 9], [1, 8, 10], [1, 9, 10], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 5], [2, 3, 6], [2, 3, 7], [2, 3, 8], [2, 3, 9], [2, 3, 10], [2, 4, 5], [2, 4, 6], [2, 4, 7], [2, 4, 8], [2, 4, 9], [2, 4, 10], [2, 5, 6], [2, 5, 7], [2, 5, 8], [2, 5, 9], [2, 5, 10], [2, 6, 7], [2, 6, 8], [2, 6, 9], [2, 6, 10], [2, 7, 8], [2, 7, 9], [2, 7, 10], [2, 8, 9], [2, 8, 10], [2, 9, 10], [3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 6], [3, 4, 7], [3, 4, 8], [3, 4, 9], [3, 4, 10], [3, 5, 6], [3, 5, 7], [3, 5, 8], [3, 5, 9], [3, 5, 10], [3, 6, 7], [3, 6, 8], [3, 6, 9], [3, 6, 10], [3, 7, 8], [3, 7, 9], [3, 7, 10], [3, 8, 9], [3, 8, 10], [3, 9, 10], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 7], [4, 5, 8], [4, 5, 9], [4, 5, 10], [4, 6, 7], [4, 6, 8], [4, 6, 9], [4, 6, 10], [4, 7, 8], [4, 7, 9], [4, 7, 10], [4, 8, 9], [4, 8, 10], [4, 9, 10], [5, 6, 7], [5, 6, 8], [5, 6, 9], [5, 6, 10], [5, 7, 8], [5, 7, 9], [5, 7, 10], [5, 8, 9], [5, 8, 10], [5, 9, 10], [6, 7, 8], [6, 7, 9], [6, 7, 10], [6, 8, 9], [6, 8, 10], [6, 9, 10], [7, 8, 9], [7, 8, 10], [7, 9, 10], [8, 9, 10]]
```

However I'm not sure how to pick out of these subarrays the exact amount so that each person receives `n` reviews out of the `m` people. Maybe there's some sort of name related to this kind of problems which I'm not familiar with.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the m number build the array of "fellows":

```
m = 10
fellows = m.times.map{ |i| i }
#=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Then, each fellow reviews the next three:

```
n = 3    
reviews = fellows.map.with_index.with_object({}) { |(f, i), h| h[f] = fellows.rotate(i)[1..n] }
#=> {0=>[1, 2, 3], 1=>[2, 3, 4], 2=>[3, 4, 5], 3=>[4, 5, 6], 4=>[5, 6, 7], 5=>[6, 7, 8], 6=>[7, 8, 9], 7=>[8, 9, 0], 8=>[9, 0, 1], 9=>[0, 1, 2]}
```

Maybe it is required to randomize?

```
reviews = fellows.shuffle!.map....
```

Comment: simplifies to `fellows = 0.upto(m -1); fellows.zip(fellows.cycle.each_cons(n)).to_h`

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything. I suggest you delete your first sentence. Note: `fellows = (0..m-1).to_a`.

Comment: @engineersmnky, thanks. `cycle`, I forgot it. I posted the first working code I come up with. Also, I think it should `reviews = fellows.shuffle!.map....`, bang!, to work properly

Comment: @iGian all depends on what the desired result is `shuffle!` will cause the keys and the values to be shuffled, where as `shuffle` will cause just the keys to shuffle. I am still unclear what the desired output even is

Comment: That's an excellent approach. At first I wasn't 100% sure if just rotating would be compliant for every case where `m < n`, looking at it from a sorted perspective made it very simple to understand. Thank you.